# Where is the code of typescript abstract classes?

Tags: angular

I would like to find out more about the Angular Renderer listen/globalListen function, but the API docs are very poor.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html#!#listen-anchor

Therefore I wanted to check on the source code of the class itself but all I can find is the abstract class, that doesn't contain the method definitions. How can I find the code ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/render/api.ts

Comment: I know where there angular project is on Github. And I know where the Renderer class is located. The problem is this is an abstract class. There is no method bodies.

Comment: Then look for **implementations**, e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22implements+Renderer%22 Abstract classes don't have to have implementations, *that's the point*; see [the TS docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes).

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's it. I didn't look for the dom_renderer.ts implementation. (I knew about abstract classes, but didn't think about the Dom Renderer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe wrote in the comments above, the abstract classes don't (have to) contain implementations. I was looking for the [`DomRenderer` class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/21030e9a1cf30e8101399d8535ed72d847a23ba6/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L69), that implements the `Renderer` abstract class.